# Call an image into javascript jQuery

Tags: jquery, slickquiz

I'm running a quiz using SlickQuiz, I'm amending the .js file and instead of showing the question through text I want to call an image in. here is the code:

```
{
    "q": "This is the question area where I'd prefer to call an image?",
    "a": [
        {"option": "Answer 1",    "correct": false},
        {"option": "Answer 2",     "correct": true},
        {"option": "Answer 3",      "correct": false}// no comma here
    ],
    "correct": "<p><span>Well done!</span> The correct answer is Answer 2.</p>",
    "incorrect": "<p><span>Incorrect</span> The correct answer is Answer 2.</p>" // no comma here
}
```

So the "q" line is where I want to call an image in. 
Anyone got any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that's the easiest thing to try - just throw an `<img>` in there and see if it works. If not, you'll have to either edit the plugin or change the HTML after it's generated by SlickQuiz, neither of which is particularly elegant.

Comment: why don't you just use <img> tag, set the href and when you insert it into the html, the image is loaded....

Comment: Sorry folks, should have mentioned, I had tried a <img> tag, this kills all the coding.

Comment: q is a html string, it populates a <div>. You can see the original files here: https://github.com/jewlofthelotus/SlickQuiz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, pointed me in the right direction in the end.

Just needed to escape the quotes in the img tag;

```
"q": "<img src=\"../images/q1.png\" />",
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes sir this is a pretty simple fix. Just try adding this code below. It worked for me as well.

`<img src=\"your.image.whatever\"/>`